# Изменить тип данных столбца

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

На sql server в таблице 'table' есть столбец 'date', в котором хранится дата в формате numeric: 1519721624578 - пример одной произвольной записи. Это кол-во миллисекунд, прошедших с 01.01.1970 (так оракл хранит дату, данные sql server получает с оракла через openquery). Нужно преобразовать этот столбец, чтобы дата отображалась нормально.
Пробую вывести через select:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '01.01.1970') + CAST(date/86400000 as datetime)
from table
```

Все работает, но хочу изменить сам столбец:

```
update table set date = (CONVERT(datetime, '01.01.1970') + CAST(date/86400000 as datetime))
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to numeric is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Что логично, потому что новый и старый типы данных не совпадают. ALter table alter column не работает, потому что столбец уже заполнен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select DATEADD(SS, 1519721624578/1000, '1970/01/01 00:00:00')
```

Но она даст дату только с точностью до секунд. Прямо в миллисекундах передать dateadd() невозможно, так как она принимает тип данных int. Если миллисекунды нужны, то необходимо дополнительно добавить к полученной дате остаток от деления исходного числа на 1000 как миллисекунды.

При передаче данных из оракл через openquery дату стоит сконвертировать на этапе выборки из Oracle на его диалекте `date'1970-01-01'+ 1519721624578/1000/3600/24`

Comment: Точность до миллисекунд не нужна. Но я интересовался, можно ли преобразовать данные в столбце и тип данных столбца, не создавая временных, так как в таблице таких столбцов с датами много.

Comment: @АмирЗакиров Думаю в этом случае надо что бы оракл уже вернул дату в нормальном виде. дописал в ответе конвертацию как она будет в оракле. Либо уже на стороне sql-server сделать view на эти таблицы, с конвертацией

Comment: Пробовал так делать. В Openquery запрос к ораклу помещается в одинарные кавычки(имя_сервера, 'запрос'), а в самом запросе в функции конвертации даты так же присутствуют одинарные кавычки. В других местах это решается заменой одинарных на двойные или использованием одинарных два раза, но именно в to_date('10.01.1970'), ни первое, ни второе не работает.

Comment: @АмирЗакиров А какую нибудь обратную косую черту не провбовали (не знаю как в openquery с этим работают). В крайнем случае можно сделать view с конвертацией со стороны оракла и делать select из нее

Comment: на оракле доступ только на чтение, в этом и заключается самая огромная проблема!)) Думаю, напишу триггер или процедуру на sql server, которая будет создавать доп столбцы, преобразовывать в них дату, а изначальные столбцы удалять.

Comment: @АмирЗакиров Вот тут http://beerhead.ru/bi/2011/using-openquery-with-linked-servers/ в примерах, очень интересные replace. они делают четверные апострофы, с чего бы это ... может в openquery как то так их надо передавать, ставя по 4 раза

Comment: Спасибо. Решил все же пробовать и с оракла получать уже преобразованные данные. Проблема оказалась связана с языками. Вот решение:
to_date(''01.01.1970'', ''DD.MM.YY'', ''NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'')+trunc(au.created_dttm/86400000). Это, конечно, загромождает запрос, так как в openquery ограничение на 4000 символов, но решает проблему кардинально